# MemSQL Ops password security

Tags: singlestore

I followed the instructions at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-memsql-on-ubuntu-14-04

MemSQL Ops is running on http://my_server_ip:9000

Is there a way to password protect the MemSQL Ops interface so the outside world cannot access my database configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the memsql-ops command line interface to create a superuser in Ops that effectively password protects Ops. Once a superuser is defined, all Ops UI users will need to login before they can see any information.

http://docs.memsql.com/latest/ops/cli/SUPERUSER-ADD/

Learn more about the memsql-ops command line interface by visiting the MemSQL documentation or by SSHing into your host machine and running memsql-ops --help

Comment: No problem! I'm glad it helped.